# Живая строка JS jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Всем привет, очень нужна помощь.
Создавая новый тестовый блок в меню методом .append, тем же методом создаю div на странице. Все с уникальными id
как правильно написать конструкцию с методом .keyup, что бы вводя текст он отображался в соответствующем div.

`

```
            var add = 1;
            $('#add').click(function() {

                var b_r = "<button "+"id="+"itb_" + add +  ">"+"Remove"+"</button>";

                $('.items').append("<div " +"class=item"+">"
                                        +"Item #"+add
                                        +"<textarea "+"id="+"it_"+add+" type="+"text"+" value="+"1"+ ">"
                                        +"</textarea>"
                                        + b_r
                                    +"</div>");

                $('.page').append("<div id="+"val_it_" + add + ">"</div>");

                $('#it_'+add).keyup(function(){

                        var value = $(this).val();

                        $('#val_it_'+add).text(value);

                });


                add++;
            });
```

`

[image: Вот что должно полчится]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схема следующая, для `<textarea>` добавь общий класс + добавь атриубут типа `data-it` где будет ссылка на id нужного элемента куда надо записать инфу, и на этот класс вешай отдельно обработчик, т.е. вынеси вообще из-за блока `click`

```
$('.example-class-name').keyup(function(){
    // пример, тут как твоей душе уже угодно
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.val(),
        id = $this.attr('data-it');
    $(id).text(value);
});
```

Comment: Вместо `$this.attr('data-it');` в `jquery` есть метод `.data()` именно для `data` атрибутов. И можно писать так. `$this.data('it');`

Comment: ага, бывали траблы с `ie` то ли с `firefox` (не помню версию), поэтому привык использовать только `attr`

Comment: С `firefox` ни каких проблем, а с `ie`, Он уже `старик` и еще смотря какую версию  `jquery` используешь.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan не спорю, спасибо за замечание, но я лично только `attr` использую для работы с атрибутами

Comment: Я и не говорю что это не правильно.

Comment: а я и не говорю, что вы сказали, что это неправильно :) думаю на этом можно закончить